# Finding Correlation coefficient in Regression equation

Tags: regression, correlation

> If the regression equation as $\displaystyle \hat{y}=1-0.30x$ and $r^2=0.64$. Then the correlation coefficient is

Here is what I've tried: We have given $r^2=0.64$. Then we have $r=0.8$. So our correlation coefficient is $0.8$.

But it is unclear to me what is the use of the regression equation in the above problem.

Answer (score 2):

The regression equation is there to tell you the direction of the correlation. If you know $r^2 = 0.64$, then $r = \pm 0.8$. To decide on whether the correlation is positive or negative you should look at the slope of the regression line. Since the slope is negative, $r = -0.8$.